# raspberry pi touch screen - Pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, pygame, touchscreen, raspberry-pi2

I am using a block of code from a [website](http://jeremyblythe.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/raspberry-pi-pygame-ui-basics.html) here is the section I am using:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#Setup the GPIOs as outputs - only 4 and 17 are available
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)

#Colours
WHITE = (255,255,255)

os.putenv('SDL_FBDEV', '/dev/fb1')
os.putenv('SDL_MOUSEDRV', 'TSLIB')
os.putenv('SDL_MOUSEDEV', '/dev/input/touchscreen')

pygame.init()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
lcd = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 240))
lcd.fill((0,0,0))
pygame.display.update()

font_big = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

touch_buttons = {'17 on':(80,60), '4 on':(240,60), '17 off':(80,180), '4 off':(240,180)}

for k,v in touch_buttons.items():
    text_surface = font_big.render('%s'%k, True, WHITE)
    rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=v)
    lcd.blit(text_surface, rect)

pygame.display.update()

while True:
    # Scan touchscreen events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if(event.type is MOUSEBUTTONDOWN):
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            print pos
        elif(event.type is MOUSEBUTTONUP):
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            print pos
            #Find which quarter of the screen we're in
            x,y = pos
            if y < 120:
                if x < 160:
                    GPIO.output(17, False)
                else:
                    GPIO.output(4, False)
            else:
                if x < 160:
                    GPIO.output(17, True)
                else:
                    GPIO.output(4, True)
    sleep(0.1)
```

When I run it (with root privileges) I get this error:

```
  File "touchscreen.py", line 20, in <module>
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

I am trying to create a simple button interface on a raspberry pi touchscreen for my project, any working soloution would be welcomed. It does not matter to me if this code is repaired alternative code would be equally valid.

Thank you,

Matthew Wood

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, the solution was that the input device was called mouse0 not touchscreen.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
disp_no = os.getenv('DISPLAY')
if disp_no:
    print "I'm running under X display = {0}".format(disp_no)
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

else:
    drivers = ['directfb', 'fbcon', 'svgalib']
    found = False
    for driver in drivers:
        if not os.getenv('SDL_VIDEODRIVER'):
            os.putenv('SDL_VIDEODRIVER', driver)
        try:
            pygame.display.init()
        except pygame.error:
            print 'Driver: {0} failed.'.format(driver)
            continue
        found = True
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
        break

    if not found:
        raise Exception('No suitable video driver found!')

os.environ["SDL_FBDEV"] = "/dev/fb1"
os.environ["SDL_MOUSEDEV"] = "/dev/input/touchscreen"
os.environ["SDL_MOUSEDRV"] = "TSLIB"
```

for example directly above your for k,v line

This will try to either run in X-Windows (with visible mouse pointer, or in the best available frame buffer driver